# Powerpoint - VBA Only - Insert custom bullets list

Tags: vba, powerpoint, bullet

Hope you are doing well. 
I am on a VBA code (only, not XML) to insert a custom bullet list in the selected object (textbox, shape etc.) such as 
[image: Expected]
I tried the following code:

```
Sub CustomBulletsVBAOnly()

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.textFrame
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(1)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 140
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(2)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 141
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(3)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 142
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(4)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 143
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(5)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 144
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(6)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 145
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(7)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 146
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(8)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 147
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(9)
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Font.name = "Webdings"
        .ParagraphFormat.bullet.Character = 148
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

The code is currently not working.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks. Naxos

Comment: Please edit the question to explain ***how** the code "isn't working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tries I found the code if someone needs it please find it below.

```
Sub InsertCustomBulletList()
 If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionText Then
     With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(1).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(2).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(3).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(4).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(5).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(6).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(7).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(8).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(9).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(10).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(11).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(12).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
               End With
                 With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(13).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(14).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(15).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(16).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(17).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(18).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(19).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Lines(20).ParagraphFormat.bullet
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .UseTextColor = msoTrue
                    .Font.name = "Your font"
                    .Character = 0  'Character in ASCII Dec
                    .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
    End With
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not necessary. This numbering style is already built into PowerPoint. Here is the code to apply it:

```
Sub NumberStyle()
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2. _
    TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
    .Type = msoBulletNumbered
    .Style = msoBulletCircleNumWdBlackPlain
  End With
End Sub
```

Here's my article explaining PowerPoint numbering styles: [OOXML Hacking: PowerPoint Numbering Styles](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2017/06/xml-hacking-powerpoint-numbering-styles/)

Comment: I know. The reason why I post this question is because I need it on another case especially with another font.